# Transaction not showing on Kovan etherscan even after its status showed transaction mined and executed successfully

Tags: etherscan, testnets, infura, kovan

I have my contract deployed on Kovan Testnet and from remix IDE I called one of the functions of my smart contract through remix itself. Now, the status of transaction shows "transaction mined and executed successfully" and I'm also able to retrieve the transaction hash but when I view it on Etherscan.io it shows me "Sorry we are unable to locate this TxnHash."

Please help me out as I'm also using this Smart contract in my final year project.

Comment: Yes, the transaction hash was perfect. I was already getting the transaction status has "transaction successfully mined and executed". 

Howevere, the issue is resolved now. The problem was with Etherscan. It got resolved after around 12 hours. Now, I can see all the transactions that I performed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I found out that the problem was with Etherscan explorer. It wasn't showing Kovan's transactions even after they were mined successfully. Later I, changed it to Rinkeby. I suppose that'll be a stable one hopefully.